# Java Library that supports Quaternions Octonions, Sedenions?

Tags: quaternions, octonions, sedenions

I would like to experiment with multi dimensional complex numbers such as quaternions octonions, sedenions.

I know Apache Commons Maths supports Quaternions, and I've found (although cannot download) ca.uwaterloo.alumni.dwharder.Numbers.Sedenion

Are there any open source Java libraries that support multi dimensional Algebras?

Comment: One could always implement the octonions (and the the sedenions) by expressing them in terms of quaternions (for which you already have an implementation) using the Cayley construction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/James1345/Sedenion).